# Regex on Spotfire- Returning the right side of a condition

Tags: regex, spotfire

Is there any way to return the right side of a specific word? For example, *[column 1]* is written in a consistent form, all the way up to a point. After that point, there exists a location name.

examples of column 1 values (length can vary):

*[column 1]*= "Annual Inspection PM Location 12"

*[column 1]* = "Annual Inspection PM Facility abc"

*[column 1]*= "Annual Inspection PM Spot 1"

All in all, I would like to know if there's a regex expression that I can use in Spotfire to dissect the first part "Annual Inspection PM" from the "Location". The goal is to be able to return the "location"/right side of *[column 1]* after the word "PM".

This is what I've got so far, but it's not working for me:

RXReplace([scheduled_maintenance_description],"(PM\b)","$","")

Comment: Try  `RXReplace([scheduled_maintenance_description],".*\\bPM\\b (.+)","$1","")`

Comment: You're amazing, this worked! Thank you! Can you explain what the code means so that I can develop an understanding for future cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `RXReplace` on this page [Text Functions](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/12.2.0/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire-analyst_UsersGuide/ncfe/ncfe_text_functions.htm) you could using a capture group (group 1), and use that group in the replacement using `$1` as the notation:

```
RXReplace([scheduled_maintenance_description],".*\\bPM (.+)","$1","")
```

The pattern matches:

- `.*` Match the whole line
- `\\bPM`  A word boundary to prevent a partial word match, then match `PM`
- `(.+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1 or more times any character

You can see an example of the replacements at this [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/9H90Ef/1).